# Json http respone, if else statement

Tags: c++, json

I CANNOT ALTER THE JSON RESPONSE, SHOWN BELOW.

I want to be able to detect when the POST message was successfully entered into the database. When the data is successfully entered the response is:

{"status":"success","message":"successfully inserted"}

I want to then use an if-else statement in Arduino to detect when this is received from the server. So my code will look something like this:

```
while(client.available()) 
{
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.print(line);

    Serial.print("\n");

    if(line == "{"status":"success","message":"successfully inserted"}")
    {
      update_var++;
      Serial.print("SUCCESSFUL");
      break;
    }

    else
    {
      Serial.print("UNSUCCESSFUL");
    }
    
}
```

However, a problem immediately arises in the if statement. This is due to the quotation marks also appearing in the string. How do I use an if-else statement when receiving JSON response?

Comment: You can escape the inner quotes with a \. Instead of " do \". However, this is a mistake. You should actually do some JSON parsing, which is a little more complicated.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: @M-Chen-3 That's not valid in C++.

Comment: @tadman Man, I've been spoiled by Python. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Unrelated: Is `String` the Arduino `String` class? If so, I recommend installing [Arduino STL](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl) and use `std::string` instead. It also has a lot of other goodies like `std::vector` etc. It makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just requires escaping if you're testing literally:

```cpp
if (line == "{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"successfully inserted\"}")
```

Keep in mind this could just as easily have the keys swapped, there's no guarantee they'll be in that order. This is why using a proper JSON parser is imperative.

Comment: I cannot alter the JSON string received from the server. So what I receive is: {"status":"success","message":"successfully inserted"}. I cannot go and put additional characters into this.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the string received from the server and everything to do with how to represent that string in C++. In a double-quoted string backslash has special meaning, so `"A \"quoted\" string"` is actually, in terms of *characters*, just `A "quoted" string`. The way you represent a single double-quote character inside a C++ string is, as always, `\"`.

Comment: So how do I insert the \" part into the string recieved?

Comment: Again, **use a JSON parser** as this approach is extremely brittle. Swapping the order, introducing white-space, or adding another key doesn't change the meaning, but it *will* fail to match.

Comment: It doesn't go into the thing you receive. It doesn't matter there *because that is not source code*. This is only, specifically relevant inside of C++ source code. You'll see the same thing if you ever do JSON-inside-JSON or have quotes inside a JSON string. This is basic escaping. It is practically universal.

Comment: Thank you. Could you assit with using a JSON parse? I am confused from the link in the comment

Comment: Search for "C++ JSON parser" and you'll find all kinds of libraries. Pick one you find suits your needs and use it. There's many out there, each of which has its various benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: "So how do I insert the \" part into the string recieved?" I realise how stupid that comment was. Sorry if that frustated you..... You answer works!

Comment: Glad that's clear now. Sorry if that came off a bit terse.

Comment: Yup I understand the /" is not what is received by the server as you showed in the example in your comment above. However the string received when the data is inserted correctly is always what I showed in my post. SO it will never change. In the event the if statement returns a false which means the data sent was not delivered successfully the else statement will catch this. To allow me to know soemthing is wrong.

Comment: Learning new things is mostly frustrating but when you understand it, it's all worth it!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JSON library for parsing JSON but if that's not an option, I recommend comparing your `String` with a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (option 6 in the link) to avoid escaping of any character:

```
if(line == R"aw({"status":"success","message":"successfully inserted"})aw") {
    // ...
}
```